# How to put a text in a center of a tabularx cell in Latex?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, cell

I used a code, I have a table which created by using `tabularx`, but the problem is that, I want to remove the word MADM into center of cell, and the head text into the center too, but I won't change the place of Text. as shown in picture :

[image]

I want to change it like that :

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % new
\usepackage{enumitem}                               % new
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, 
                  after=\end{minipage}                   
                  }



    \begin{table} [htp]
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
{|
L| 
p{0.18\textwidth} |
p{0.18\textwidth} | 
}  
  \hline
Text  & 
  Text 
            &   Text
            
              \\ 
    \hline
    
MADM &

\begin{tabitemize}
                \item   Text Text Text. 
                \item Text Text Text.
                \item Text Text Text.
                \item  Text Text-Text.
                \item Text Text.
 \end{tabitemize}
 & 
 
\begin{tabitemize}
                \item       Text Text Text. 
                \item Text Text Text the Text Text Text Text.
 \end{tabitemize}
 
    
             \\ 
    \hline
    
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in preamble you define `tabitem` but in table you use `tabitemize` list ...
- for horizontal centering of column headers you have more possibilities:

  - use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text}`
  - use `\hfil`: `\hfil Text  & \hfil Text   & \hfil Text  \\`
  - use `\makecell` as is done in MWE below
- to move text MADM in vertical center in the first column you need to use `\multirow` instruction defined in the package with the same name

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % new
\usepackage{enumitem}                               % new
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth},
                  after=\end{minipage}
                  }

\begin{document}                 
    \begin{table} [htp]
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
    \hline
Text    &   Text    &   Text    \\
\multicell{Text}    
        &   \multicell{Text}   
            &   \multicell{Text}    \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{MADM}    
        &  \begin{tabitem}
        \item   Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text-Text.
        \item Text Text.
            \end{tabitem}
            &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item Text Text Text.
            \item Text Text Text the Text Text Text Text.
                \end{tabitem}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]